# Можно ли обрабатывать событие разблокировки экрана?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Например, чтобы сразу после разблокировки экрана запускалось приложение в фоне?

Answer (score 3):

Вам необходимо настроить ресивер для отлавливания `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT`, ну и из него уже выполнять необходимые действия.